# React: Best way to pass Firestore info to components?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can't figure out an efficient way to set a user's profile and then pass that data onwards to other components as needed.

Below is an example of my current logic, and although the app works, the rendering is not efficient. When I click on various parts of my app, the data coming from my UserProfile component is re-rendering every time causing the text to change from the initial text to the rendered data text.

**The main issue**, I believe, is the communication between the **UserProfile** and **Dashboard Home** snippets below.  I'm new to the useEffect logic, so I would imagine the inefficient setup is with that hook.

Any help or nudge in the right direction is appreciated!

Thanks

**AuthContext file => Setting the current user**

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {
    auth,
    signInWithGoogle,
    createUserProfileDocument,
    firestore,
} from '../firebase.utils';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const signup = (email, password) => {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    };

    const login = (email, password) => {
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    };

    const logout = () => {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        return auth.signOut();
    };

    const resetPassword = email => {
        return auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    };

    const updateEmail = email => {
        return currentUser.updateEmail(email);
    };

    const updatePassword = password => {
        return currentUser.updatePassword(password);
    };

    const deleteProfile = () => {
        currentUser.delete();
        firestore.doc(`users/${currentUser.uid}`).delete();
    };

    const updateName = displayName => {
        return currentUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: displayName,
        });
    };

    const setName = displayName => {
        return auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: displayName,
        });
    };

    const googleSignIn = () => {
        const google = signInWithGoogle();
        setCurrentUser(google);
        return google;
    };

    const updatePersonalSettings = data => {
        createUserProfileDocument(currentUser, data);
    };

    const updateAccountSettings = data => {
        createUserProfileDocument(currentUser, data);
    };

    console.log(currentUser);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setLoading(false);
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        login,
        signup,
        logout,
        resetPassword,
        updateEmail,
        updatePassword,
        updateName,
        setName,
        googleSignIn,
        updatePersonalSettings,
        updateAccountSettings,
        deleteProfile,
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

**UserProfile file => Setting the userInfo**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../context/auth-context';
import { createUserProfileDocument } from '../firebase.utils';

const UserProfile = () => {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const setUserData = async () => {
        if (currentUser) {
            const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(currentUser);
            userRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
                setUserInfo({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(),
                });
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setUserData();
    }, []);

    return { userInfo };
};

export default UserProfile;
```

**Dashboard home file => Example of rendering data from the UserProfile component**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import sprite from '../../../../assets/sprite.svg';
import UserProfile from '../../../../user-profile/user-profile';
import './home-dashboard.styles.scss';

const HomeDashboard = () => {
    const { userInfo } = UserProfile();

    const handleCurrentLevel = () => {
        return !userInfo || userInfo.currentLevel === undefined ? (
            <h1>Welcome! Start your eval to see your level</h1>
        ) : (
            <h1>Current Level: {userInfo.currentLevel}</h1>
        );
    };

    const handleCurrentLevelCard = () => {
        return !userInfo || userInfo.currentLevel === undefined
            ? 'Start a new eval to see your level'
            : `You scored a ${userInfo.currentLevel} in your last eval`;
    };

    return (
        <div className="home-dash">
            <div className="home-dash__title">{handleCurrentLevel()}</div>
            <div className="home-dash__cards">
                <div className="home-dash__card-1">
                    <svg className="icon home-dash__card-icon">
                        <use href={sprite + '#card-icon-success'}></use>
                    </svg>

                    <h3 className="home-dash__card-title">
                        Latest Eval Results
                    </h3>
                    <div className="home-dash__card-result-text">
                        {handleCurrentLevelCard()}
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/eval-quiz">
                        <button className="home-dash__card-btn--purple">
                            Start New Eval
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                {/* TODO Add resutls to firestore */}
                {
                    <div className="home-dash__card-2">
                        <svg className="icon home-dash__card-icon">
                            <use href={sprite + '#card-icon-lightbulb'}></use>
                        </svg>

                        <h3 className="home-dash__card-title">
                            Areas to practice
                        </h3>
                        <div className="home-dash__card-result-text">
                            We recommend working on reading skills
                        </div>
                        {/*<button className="home-dash__card-btn--blue">
                            Practice
                </button>*/}
                        <div className="home-dash__coming-soon">
                            Coming soon!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default HomeDashboard;
```

**Firestore/Firebase setup**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
});

export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
    if (!userAuth) return;

    const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`);
    const snapShot = await userRef.get();

    const { displayName, email, photoURL } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();

    if (!snapShot.exists) {
        console.log(displayName);
        try {
            await userRef.set({
                displayName,
                photoURL,
                email,
                createdAt,
                ...additionalData,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error catching data', error.message);
        }
    }

    if (snapShot.exists) {
        try {
            await userRef.update({
                displayName,
                email,
                ...additionalData,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error catching data', error.message);
        }
    }

    return userRef;
};

export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
googleProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);

export const auth = app.auth();

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this answer a draft, I've made it public in case you can piece it together but I'll update it with some documentation in the morning.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../context/auth-context';
import { createUserProfileDocument } from '../firebase.utils';

const UserProfile = () => {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!currentUser) {
            // user is signed out
            setUserInfo(null);
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        const userRef = /* ... */;
        setUserInfo(undefined); // clear stale data
        setLoading(true); // update loading status

        return userRef.onSnapshot({
            next(snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.exists) {
                    userRef
                        .set({
                            /* new data */
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            // TODO: Handle errors
                        });
                    return;
                }

                setUserInfo({
                    id: snapshot.id,
                    ...snapshot.data(),
                });
                setLoading(false);
            },
            error(err) {
                // TODO: Handle errors
            }
        });
    }, [currentUser]);

    return { userInfo }; // <-- this seems odd? missing loading?
};

export default UserProfile;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I ended up using the useContext api to pass the useInfo from Firestore to the various components. Thanks for your help!